# Travel statistics by gender and country

Tags: data-request, demographics, global, travel

Is there any statistics available that includes gender differences? I would like to know the rate of male vs female travelers. For example, something like this:

- Country: male%
- USA: 48%
- Germany: 43%
- Japan: 38%
- China: 42%

Of course it is sufficient if you can compute it by manipulating the raw data.

Comment: What do you mean by travel? international air travel? any mode?

Comment: @Skram Yes international air travel. I didn't mind the mode... I don't believe the government provide the datasets that is so specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a global database but Eurostat does provide some insights into European countries if that is of interest. You can find their tourism database [here](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/tourism/data/database).

If you navigate through `tour_dem` > `tour_dem_tt` > `tour_dem_ttsd` > `tour_dem_ttsex` you will find what you are looking for. The data is available for viewing in Eurostats interface or as a downloadable `tsv`.

If you want to compare this to expenditure by gender you can find this data in `tour_dem_ex` > `tour_dem_exsd` > `tour_dem_exsex`.

The raw tourism data is split into different variables. You will have `Personal` trips as well as `Professional, business` trips and `Domestic`, `Outbound` or `All countries of the world` trips. You can also see amount of time spent by `1 night or over`, `from 1 to 3 nights` and `4 nights or over`

Direct links to the raw data can be found here:

[Number of trips by country and sex (and type of trip, length of trip, type of destination)](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?dir=data&sort=1&sort=2&start=tour_dem_ttsex)

[Expenditure on tourism by country and sex (and type of trip, length of trip, type of destination)](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?dir=data&sort=1&sort=2&start=tour_dem_exsex)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know which encoding it is written? I can't read the tsv datasets via UTF-8 or SJIS...

Comment: Ah, it worked if I read the data as SDMX. Thank, it is what I was looking for!